# Angular2 CLI: How to refactor component name?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

Suppose I create a component with a certain name, let's say 'Car', and I want to change its name to 'Bicycle', meaning that the file names that create this component will be changes and so does the name of the class and the imports used in the current code, is there any "quick" way to do it by CLI ?

Comment: You should do it manually change class name file name everywhere it exported and imported and update the class name in NgModule

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49631019/4654957

Answer (score 0):

Cli is not meant for such task. If you want support for this you can look into Webstorm IDE

Answer (score 0):

Cli doesn't support such feature you can go for an IDE.

If you want to know how can you acheive this you can refer my previous answer

[How to rename a component in Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411036/how-to-rename-a-component-in-angular-cli/47920931#47920931)