# How to rename a component in Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, rename, angular-components

Is there any shortcut to rename a component with the Angular CLI other than manually editing all the component files such as folder name, .css, .ts, spec.ts and app.module.ts?

Comment: Just rename the selector, if you want to change in html tag. If you want to change the class, u need to do it manually.

Comment: Until they add in `ng destroy` you're not in luck...

Comment: You can monitor the feature in this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900

Comment: search and replace, rename a couple of file/ directories.... job done

Comment: [This is the new thread](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/815), since the angular team decided to [not include this within their cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900#issuecomment-642889197).

Comment: This post already has 200k views, thats how much people need this. Will they change their mind actually provide this feature for the love of fellow developer?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

No!

There is no command which will change the name of all files generated using the component create command. So created `ts`, `html`, `css/scss`, `.spec.ts` 
 files need to be manually renamed/edited.

I am a frequent user of `angular cli` and I think this would be a nice-to-have command as some time we just create angular components and need to rename them. As this rename command is not there, deleting the created angular component, directive, etc and again running the command to create the component is really a pain.

Here is the discussion link to add this feature [rename angular component](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900)

Comment: new `WebStorm 2018.1.2` on words allow renaming of the component but never used it. will give a try later someday

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I think JetBrains had that for years in IntelliJIdea and in most of their IDEs including webstorm

Comment: In VSCode for example, when there is something wrong (imported file that doesn't exist, non-existing component and so on), you can see error indications in the files explorer pane on the left. So, in my case I needed to rename a component, I just renamed its folder and inner file names, then I just followed all the error indications, modifying the name of this component accordingly. I guess this feature exists also in other modern IDEs these days... But to have an angular-cli command that does this automatically (much like "ng g c ...") would be great, though! Happy coding! :)

Comment: There is a discussion about this feature since 2016 about this feature: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900 
All requests for such a feature are linked to this thread and closed. @AniruddhaDas would you mind adding this to the answer?

Comment: @Stefan added now. see if looks okey, feel free to edit as well.

Comment: There should be rather `move` command instead of `rename`, because `move` command could be used as `rename` command as well.

Comment: "nice-to-have" is an extreme understatement. It's 2023 and this feature is still missing. Sad we have to rely on VSCode for basic CLI functionality. Components are a core aspect of Angular and surely Google has the resources to handle this

Answer (score 88):

Yes!

Now there is.

There is an Extension for VS Code to do all of these steps for you. It's called [Rename Angular Component](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomwhite007.rename-angular-component).

I have hopes of porting it to WebStorm and a Schematic later.

Previously, it took at least three semi-automated steps in VS Code as a minimum. This Extension does all of them.

I realise this is promoting my own solution. But it is free, open source, and the complete answer. If it doesn't do everything you're looking for, you can post issues on the repo, and it will be improved.

Comment: *Note: It does not rename the component name strings in .spec files. Check: https://github.com/tomwhite007/rename-angular-component/issues/34.

Comment: It was able to rename component name strings in .spec files for me. Granted it's now 4/18/23.

Comment: Awesome, works like charm! Changed the component name and the html where it was called.

Comment: Works like Magic ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Also note it does not rename routes so you'll probably want to manually update those to reflect the actual component name

Comment: Nice but it doesn't update routes and imports of those components

Comment: This solution works on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 71):

Currently Angular CLI doesn't support the feature of renaming or refactoring code.

You can achieve such functionality with the help of some IDE.

Intellij, Eclipse, VSCode etc.. has default support the refactoring.

Nowadays VSCode is showing some uptrend,personally I'm a fan of this

**Refactoring with VSCode**

**Determinig reference** : -
VS Code help you find all references of a variable by selecting variable and pressing shortcut `SHIFT` + `F12`. This works incredibly well with Type Script.

**Renaming all instances of reference** :-
After finding all the references you can press `F2` will open a popup and you can change the value and click enter this will update all the instances of reference.

**Renaming files and imports**
You can rename a file and its import references with a plugin. More details can be found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts)

[image]

With above steps after renaming the variables and files you can achieve the angular component renaming.

Comment: You talk about references, files and imports, but what about renaming components?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni angular-cli doesn't support renaming.The task of renaming can be achieved with these three steps.

Comment: Wow, love this extension!

Answer (score 14):

Here is a **checklist** I use to rename a component:

1.Rename the component class (VSCode **Rename Symbol** will update all the references)

```
<Old Name>Component => <New Name>Component
```

2.Rename @Component selector along with references (use VSCode's **Replace in Files**):

```
app-<old-name> => app-<new-name>

Result:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-<old-name>' => 'app-<new-name>',
  ...
})

<app-{old-name}></app-{old-name}> => <app-{new-name}></app-{new-name}>
```

3.Rename component folder (when renaming folder in VSCode, it will update references in module and other components)

```
src\app\<module>\<old-name> => src\app\<module>\<new-name>
```

4.Rename component files (renaming **manually** will be the fastest, but you can also use a terminal to rename all at once)

```
<old-name>.component.* => <new-name>.component.*

Bash:
find . -name "<old-name>.component.*" -exec rename 's/\/<old-name>\.component/\/<new-name>.component/' '{}' +

PowerShell: 
Get-Item <old-name>.component.* | % { Rename-Item $_ <new-name>.component.$($_.Extension) }

Cmd:
rename <old-name>.component.* <new-name>.component.*
```

5.Replace file references in @Component (use VSCode's **Replace in Files**):

```
<old-name>.component => <new-name>.component

Result:
@Component({
  ...
  templateUrl: './<old-name>.component.html' => './<old-name>.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./<old-name>.component.scss'] => ['./<new-name>.component.scss']
})
```

That should be sufficient

Comment: thanks this is a great checklist. You'd think given there is a tedious but fairly straightforward manual process for this, you'd think somebody would've automated it and added it as an add-in to VS Code

Comment: super handy...!

Answer (score 5):

While the OP asks for a CLI command, some of the answers focus on the IDEs. In this answer I just confirm, that the current WebStorm/IntelliJ does allow renaming the component. All that needs to be done is attempting to rename the class in the `.ts` file. You will be presented with:

[image]

and the rename will be performed in all relevant places.

Comment: This was first reported in the current thread by @Aniruddha Das

Comment: Note that this will not rename component selector appropriately

Answer (score 2):

I personally have not found any command for the same. Just make a new component (renamed name) and copy paste  the previous component's `html`, `css`, and `ts`. In `ts` obviously the class name would be replaced. Its the safest method but does take a little time.

Answer (score 1):

In WebStorm, you can right click → Refactor → Rename on the name of the component in the TypeScript file and it will change the name everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the files and components as you normally would think, then restart `ng serve`. Easy peasy.

Rename the files, paths, and references. The key is that you have to close your running server and start it again after everything is renamed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rename cli command yet. But the easiest way I have found to solve this problem is to generate a new component on the cli and copy the contents into the new component.
Then delete the original component and you will have one error for each spot in your codebase where you need to rename to the new component name. Once all the errors are dealt with you are done! :)

PS: Also you will have to delete the import statements for the old component.

Answer (score 0):

As the first answer indicated, currently there is no way to rename components so we're all just talking about work-arounds!
This is what i do:

1. Create the new component you liked.

   ng generate component newName
2. Use Visual studio code editor or whatever other editor to then  conveniently move code/pieces side by side!
3. In Linux, use grep & sed (find & replace) to find/replaces references.

   grep -ir "oldname"

   cd your folder

   sed -i 's/oldName/newName/g' *

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **VS Code**, you can rename the `.ts, .html, .css/.scss, .spec.ts` files and the IDE will take care of the imports for you. Therefore there will be no complaints from the files that import files from your component (such as `app.module.ts`). However, you will still have to rename the component name everywhere it is being used.

Answer (score 0):

To change the component name in Angular, you need to follow these steps:

Open the file containing the component that you want to rename.

Locate the `@Component` decorator above the component class definition.

Change the selector property in the `@Component` decorator to the new name that you want to give to your component.

For example, if you want to change the component name from my-old-component to my-new-component, you would do the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-new-component',
  ...
})

export class MyOldComponent {
  ...
}
```

Save the file.
That's it! You have successfully changed the component name in Angular.

Keep in mind that you may also need to update any references to the component in other parts of your application, such as in templates or in routing configurations.