# Changing the name of a component in Angular 12

Tags: angular, components, angular-cli, rename

What is the proper way to rename a component in angular? Is there a command in the CLI to do so, or should I do the renaming manually?

Comment: Is this still applicable today? Since the question was 4 years ago @YongShun

Comment: It seems there is still no official support from CLI to rename components. We have to do it manually wiz-a-wiz be at the IDE's mercy to rename all the imports.

Comment: It still an open discussion about it : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900

Answer (score 0):

Particularly, It seems that there is still no official support from the Angular CLI to rename components. The only solution right know is doing the following:

1. Rename all the files in the component folder

> `<new-name>.component.css`, `<new-name>.component.html`, `<new-name>.component.spec.ts`, `<new-name>.component.ts`.

2. Rename the paths to templateUrl and styleUrls under the `@Component` Type Decorator in `<new-name>.component.ts`.
3. Rename the Class name in `<new-name>.component.ts`.
4. Modify the import of the component in and its declaration under the `@NgModule` decorator in the `app.module.ts` file.

---

**Edit No.1:**

Check the answer of the link below:

[How to rename a component in Angular CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411036/how-to-rename-a-component-in-angular-cli)

**There is also an open discussion on Github regarding the same topic:**

[Rename/Remove/Move components in Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900)